# Finding the proper keyword and category for Google pytrends

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, reinforcement-learning, google-trends

I am trying to extract pytrends results for a given keyword for a stock market project, where I utilize the search strength as a state-space for my RL trading agent. While gathering search data for google pytrends `https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends`, I am confused about what keyword to pass. **Like for the company Amazon, should I pass Amazon or Amazon.com or Amazon Company? Because only Amazon would mean the rainforests. Similarly for Apple, should I pass Apple Inc. (which is the original name as per Yahoo financials) or Apple (it may mean the fruit)?** I tried both of these for Apple, when I used Apple Inc., the trends column was very sparse and stratified. below is the data for the last 100 days.
[image]

Now, when I passed Apple only, it was not sparse but the minimum value was 70.
[image]

For Tesla, If I pass in Tesla Motors Inc., the data is very sparse.
[image]

If I pass Tesla, the search trends are not sparse, but I am not sure if I can trust the results.
[image]
I tried two categories, 5 (Compute and Electronics or CE) and 13 (Internet and Telecom or IT).
[image]
Which one should I trust for a stock market project?
I encountered a similar situation for Amazon. So what is the correct format for passing, particularly if I am concerned with stock market data?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use Category and topic/searchterm for more specific searches, like for Apple Inc., you can search in "Mobile Phones" category and "Apple Inc." topic, and for apple fruit, you can search by "Apple" fruit or "apple" with "Fruits & Vegetables" Category

Comment: Is searching by category included in pytrends? I couldn't find that functionality in the library that I am using https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends.

Comment: Yes, "cat" parameter in api is used for category search, Use this https://github.com/pat310/google-trends-api/wiki/Google-Trends-Categories to get code of particular and pass it in cat parameter

Comment: Would cat=3 (Internet and Telecom) suffice for Apple incorporation and give a accurate representation for stock market?

Comment: You mean cat=13, I am not sure if it is the correct category, I guess 13 will be a little broader category, may be try a little specific, may be 382 or 390 will be helpful

Comment: My main aim is to get pytrends to calculate strength of a trend related to stock market, so probably Mobile phones for apple would be too much narrow. Am I getting anything wrong?

Comment: I guess, according to your usecase 13 will be fine

Comment: Yes, I was planning to do both for 13 and 5 (Computers & Electronics), then take the average for each day. Is it a worthy option to pursue in your opinion?